# Filter and update array of objects on condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern

I am getting documents from mongodb and storing it in books variable.
books is an array of objects on which i am trying to iterate but for this example i have kept only one object in books

```
const books = [{
        "users": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "dueDate": "2023-01-06T07:28:42.461Z"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "dueDate": "2023-01-08T07:34:46.095Z"
            }
        ],
}]
```

Here i want to compare dueDate for each object in users array and keep only that object which has dueDate less than current date along with that add an additional key of fine inside that object.

here is the function i wrote for it

```
books.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
    arrayItem.users = arrayItem.users.filter(
      (user) => user.dueDate < new Date().toISOString()
    );
  });
```

by this i am able to filter objects less than cuurent date but i cannot add addition key value pair to the object

My answer look like

```
books=[{
        "users": [
            {
                "id": "63abd9ed787e941505b3a816",
                "dueDate": "2023-01-06T07:28:42.461Z"
            }
        ],
}]
```

but i want it like this where one day delay has 100 rupees as fine
fine = (dueDate-current date)*100

```
books=[{
        "users": [
            {
                "id": "63abd9ed787e941505b3a816",
                "dueDate": "2023-01-06T07:28:42.461Z",
                "fine":100
            }
        ],
}]
```

i tried using few things but did not workout for me. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `map()` after `filter()`in order to add a new field to each object

```js
const books = [{
  users: [
    {
      id: "1",
      dueDate: "2023-01-06T07:28:42.461Z"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      dueDate: "2023-01-08T07:34:46.095Z"
    },
  ],
}]

books.forEach((arrayItem) => {
    arrayItem.users = arrayItem.users
    .filter((user) => user.dueDate < new Date().toISOString())
    .map((user) => ({ ...user, fine: (new Date() - new Date(user.dueDate)) * 100 }));
  });
  
console.log(books)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.map`

```js
let books=[{
        "users": [
            {
                "id": "63abd9ed787e941505b3a816",
                "dueDate": "2023-01-06T07:28:42.461Z"
            }
        ],
}]

let currDate = new Date().toISOString();
let res =books.map( b => {
    return b.users = b.users.map( u => {
      return (u.dueDate < currDate) ? {...u, fine: 100} : {...u}
    } 
    );
  });

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Sir i am getting an undesired result for your solution. i have pasted the error here for your refernce. ```[[{"__parentArray":[{"id":"16","dueDate":"2023-01-06T07:28:42.461Z"},{"id":"b9","dueDate":"2023-01-08T07:34:46.095Z"}],"__index":0,"$__parent":{"_id":"33","users":[{"id":"16","dueDate":"2023-01-06T07:28:42.461Z"},{"id":"9","dueDate":"2023-01-08T07:34:46.095Z"}],},"$__":{"activePaths":{"paths":{"id":"init","dueDate":"init"},"states":{"init":{"id":true,"dueDate":true}}}},"_doc":{"id":"16","dueDate":"2023-01-06T07:28:42.461Z"},"$isNew":false,"fine":100},```

Comment: error is continued in this comment. ```{"__parentArray":[{"id":"16","dueDate":"2023-01-06T07:28:42.461Z"},{"id":"b9","dueDate":"2023-01-08T07:34:46.095Z"}],"__index":1,"$__parent":{"_id":"33","users":[{"id":"16","dueDate":"2023-01-06T07:28:42.461Z"},{"id":"b9","dueDate":"2023-01-08T07:34:46.095Z"}],},"$__":{"activePaths":{"paths":{"id":"init","dueDate":"init"},"states":{"init":{"id":true,"dueDate":true}}}},"_doc":{"id":"b9","dueDate":"2023-01-08T07:34:46.095Z"},"$isNew":false}]]```. Here we can see the fine component but not in required format.